# how to headline unit price if a whole box is bought

Tags: quantity

We sell tape and other things that come in and are sold in boxes. We don't sell those products individually. We would like to showcase the unit price though as this gives the customer a better ability to see if they are getting a good deal.

I found this plugin Product Units and Quantities but it doesn't quite do what we want. It allows you to use the unit price when creating a product but allows customers to only choose the multiples you set. This is great but if tape comes in 36, 72 etc I want to specify the number in a box and allow them to choose 1, 2 etc boxes not 36, 72 tapes. If they are allowed to choose tapes then you end up with 36 items in the basket when it is just one box.

[image]

Is there another plugin i've missed or a way around this. I imagine it must be a fairly common issue as it seems common to promote the unit price when that price is based on the purchase of a larger amount. Thanks

Comment: Your use case seems a good fit for Magento's [Bundle Products](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-bundle.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog%7CCreating%2520Products%7C_____6). Any specific reason you're not using those?

Comment: I'm not seeing it, bundles are for collecting multiple products. I don't see how using bundles could allow me to achieve what i need

Comment: Well, it theory your box is also a collection of multiple products. You can setup each item from the box as a simple product, not visible in catalog nor search if you don't want to sell them individually, then setup a bundle product that aggregates whatever combination of items you want, including how many items should be in the bundle.

Comment: Some of the products, like tape, have color options so have to be created as configurable. I can't imagine that's doable as it would need to be a configurable/bundle hybrid. I've never used bundle before so will try that for all simple products that need that treatment, thanks

Comment: You can try to set the color using the custom options for the simple products. It's interesting to see if that works out :)

Comment: It may not be the solution you want, but if you are never selling those products other than by packs, why not creating your products directly as boxes ? Like "Box of Tape (x36)".

Comment: Just couldn't work round bundle to make it do what i needed. You get a lot of other stuff with it like the price from and to. Instead i'm going to create images on the product listings page that give details of the price per item.

Comment: I know what you mean hellimac but then you get the headline price of the box which is what i wanted to avoid. I'd rather say 'come and look at this product from 72c than $25.92 for 36. It not only looks better but it gives the prospective buyer a better grasp of the deal.